# Chrome omnibox events without specific keywords?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do want to check the content written in Chrome omnibox and redirect to the proper page.

Still, I cannot use specific keywords because I do want to redirect things like `BUG-1234` to http://bugs.example.com/BUG-1234

I do have a regexp for this (as the `BUG` part can have lots of values).

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps this could be done by creating a search provider?

Comment: @Charles can you elaborate, or give some links? I would try this method too.

Comment: Normally when you type something that isn't recognized as a URL and isn't recognized as a keyword, Chrome will kick off the [default search engine](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653).  If you replaced the default search engine, you could capture these queries and take action as needed.  I don't know if this can be done through an *extension* or whether it has to be done entirely server-side.

Comment: @Charles: Chrome has an `Omnibox api` which makes this possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chrome extension can help you, with help of Omnibox.

If i understood correctly when you enter `BUG-1234` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in [Omnibox](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox), your webpage URL Should be `http://bugs.example.com/BUG-1234`

## Demonstration

I have used keyword as

> "keyword": "BUG"

BUG, you can change it as per functionality. So when you enter <kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in [chrome Omnibox](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox) , the search provider adds a custom layer as shown here

Image 1)

[image: Beginning Screen]

and when you enter 1234 and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> **or** Select the suggested URL `Open Bug %s ?`  in [Omnibox](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox), as shown here

Image 2)

[image]

It opens a web page with URL as shown here, where i used `http://bugs.example.com` as a test URL, which can be extended further.

Image 3)

[image]

#### manifest.json

Registered background Page and [Omnibox](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/omnibox) with Chrome Extension, and added related permissions.

```
{
    "name": "Bug Tracker",
    "description": "This integrates chrome omnibox with bug search",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "omnibox": {
        "keyword": "BUG"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

#### background.js

Script for Custom Suggestions

```
//Set Text to show for custom suggested URL(s)
chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
    "description": "Open Bug %s ?"
});

//Fired when Enter or a suggested Link is selected
chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function (bugId) {
    //Use your custom URL
    chrome.tabs.update({
        "url": "http://bugs.example.com/BUG-" + bugId
    }, function () {
        console.log("Bug Page is open");
    });
    console.log("Input Entered is " + bugId);
});
```

## References

- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html)
- [Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)

Comment: There is one major problem: I have a list of about 150 keywords, now I do a regexp that detects if a piece of text matches the pattern but adding them as keywords is not going to work. In addition it will create strange behaviours: for example you have the key "MA" and you want to search for "mad dogs".

Comment: Thanks, your answer was more than good and valid. Weird but now I encountered a weird issue, while suggestion works very well, I do not get redirected at all when I press enter. Is link onInputEntered is just ignored. Also I suspect that your code became outdated based on the https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs